# What are some proposed solutions to preventing ASIC's from mining Monero?

Tags: mining, proof-of-work, randomjs

Monero forks every 6 months or so to prevent ASICs, but this doesn't fully deter ASICs from being built. Even with the new proposed RandomX pow algo, eventually ASICs will be built. What are some other proposed solutions to prevent ASICs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Monero forks every 6 months or so to prevent ASICs

Monero does a fork, which we call a *network upgrade*, roughly every 6 months. The upgrade isn't *specifically* to "prevent ASICs", that has just been one of the many things that have gone into the last couple of upgrades. Features both big and small get released in these upgrades - including ASIC resistance changes.

> Even with the new proposed RandomX pow algo, eventually ASICs will be built.

This is not necessarily correct. An ASIC (Application Specific Integrated Circuit), is built for one specific task (hence the *Application Specific* part of the name). RandomX/CryptoNightR are designed to be efficient on *general purpose* hardware by creating random tasks. A CPU (and GPU) are *general purpose* chips. For an ASIC to be developed that works with RandomX/CryptoNightR, it would essentially have to be designed in the same way as a CPU/GPU - e.g. be general purpose.

Comment: how far along are with with RandomX?

Comment: There's a pull request being reviewed right now for [CryptoNightR](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5126).

Comment: For clarity, these are totally different things, not two names for the same thing (not that I know about RandomX news).

Comment: Correct. They are different implementations, but of a similar concept.